# Configuration when upgrading from Indigo to Luna Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to upgrade my eclipse from `Indigo` to `Luna` (I know that `Luna` is not the newest but my company does not have a license for a newer version for now).
My tool uses the eclipse `Indigo` and depends on it. One of the previous developers wrote some notes on how to upgrade:

> We will need the following:
>
> 1. execution eclipse installation.
> 2. target eclipse installation
> 3. an eclipse SDK tarball to run the unit tests
>
> Change the following places in the build plug-in file:
>
> 1. Version of org.ecilpse.pdebuild (pdeBuildPluginVersion=Version)
> 2. Version of org.eclipse.equinox.launcher (equinoxLauncherPluginVersion= Version)
> 3. Execution eclipse location (eclipseLocation=Path)
> 4. Eclipse SDK tar ball (sdkTarBall=PATH-TO/eclipse-SDK-3.7-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz)

I don't understand which versions should be in the `pdeBuildPluginVersion` and in the `equinoxLauncherPluginVersion` fields - Where from I should get the needed information?
Also, what is the "Eclipse SDK tar ball" and where should I find it?

Comment: The Eclipse license is the same for all releases so I don't understand your 'company does not have a license for a newer version' statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download old Eclipse SDK versions from the Eclipse Project archive [here](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/). Choose your release and then download the Eclipe SDK tar.gz for your platform.

You find out the versions of the plugins by looking in the `plugins` directory of your Eclipse and finding the plugins, which might be something like:

```
org.eclipse.pde.build_3.9.0.v20140415-2029
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008
```

The version is the part following the '_' character